# Submit form using two values in an argument

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a value while submitting a form using javascript. Due to some programming limitations I can't use functions. so can I give two values in a single argument like this?

```
<form name="editDelete" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="theParam"/>
 ...

<a href="#" ... onclick="document.editDelete.theParam.value = 'the value'; document.editDelete.submit();">Test</a>
```

Or is there any way to submit the form sending a value using single command in `<a href>` tag itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try this final solution;

```
<form id="editDelete" ...>
<input type="hidden" id="theParam" name="theParam"/>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('theParam').value = 'thee value'; document.getElementById('editDelete').submit();">Test</a>
```

Comment: the form is not submitting in either case

Comment: did you change id properties of controls? can you share your console log?

Comment: Ok. I think there is another error. Can you share your console log from your browser when you clicked 'Test'?

Comment: Here is the console log - Uncaught TypeError: Property 'getSelection' of object [object Window] is not a function
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: dude, other parts of your code produces this errors. Because the above code only calls getElementById method. so try this solution on an empty page. If you want, you ask these errors in another question. I hope I would help  to you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use GET method in the form?
[here is an example](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_METHOD_GET.html)

```
<A HREF="../form.html?value1=West&value2=East>2 values</A>
```